# iOS - how to put UIImage and UILabel as a footer on the same line?

Tags: iphone, ios, uiview, uiimage, uilabel

I need to have a footer in my view that says "Powered by: {image_logo_of_my_company}" How do I achieve that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make a wrapper view of type `UIView` and add a `UILabel` and the logo in a `UIImageView` inside that view at the appropriate coordinates.

```
UIView *wrapper = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:footerFrame]; 
UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:
   CGRectMake(0, 0, footerFrame.size.width*0.6, footerFrame.size.height)];
UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:
   CGRectMake(footerFrame.size.width*0.6, 0, 
   footerFrame.size.width*(1.0-0.6), footerFrame.size.height)];
[wrapper addSubView:label];
[wrapper addSubView:imageView];
label.text = @"Powered by: ";
imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"logo"]; // assumes logo.png & logo@2x.png
[viewNeedingFooter addSubView:wrapper];
```

Assuming you need 60% of the width of the footer for the label and 40% for the logo.

Comment: I'm not sure how to set up the coordinates for that. Any example code would be helpful.

Comment: He already gave you an answer, it's your job to integrate it to your code. Only you know the specifics of it.